# a table of mine won't compile

Tags: tables

I have had the problem of compiling my document with the following table in it:

```
\begin{table}[H]

    \begin{center}
        \caption{Input parameters associated with the hydraulic model} \label{parametersfinal}
        \begin{tabular}{ll|ll}
            \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \textbf{Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
            \hline
            $T_{ref}$ [K] & 273,16 & $\kappa_s$ [-] & $0,5 \cdot 10^{-3}$\\
            $E_{f,ref}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & $50 \cdot 10^6$ & $r$ [-] & 0,04 \\ 
            $E_{f,inc}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}/K] & $10 \cdot 10^6$ & $\beta$ [(N/m\textsuperscript{2})\textsuperscript{-1}] & $0,08 \cdot 10^{-6}$ \\
            $\nu_f$ [-] & 0,45 & $\alpha$ [-] & 9 \\
            $G_0$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & $700 \cdot 10^6$ &  $p_{0,ref}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & -395 $\cdot 10^6$ \\    
            $\kappa_0$ [-] & 0,01 & $m$ [-] & 1 \\  
            $p^{*}_c$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & $-40 \cdot 10^3$ & $(p^{*}_{y0})_{in}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & -500 $\cdot 10^3$ \\ 
            $\lambda_0$ [-] & 0,05 & $Y_{ref}$ [m] & 0\\
            $\gamma$ [-] & 1 & $\Delta p^{*}_{y0}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & 0 \\
            $k_t$ [-] & 0,09 & $(S_{c,seg})_{in}$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & $20 \cdot 10^6$  \\
            $M$ [-] & 1,11 & $K_w$ [N/m\textsuperscript{2] & $10^9$ \\  
            \hline
        \end{tabular}       
    \end{center}
 \end{table}
```

I don't get any error messages or anything peculiar in my log, I just click the compile button and it just starts working and keeps at it forever until I abort it. Someone can help me?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you have a `documentclass` as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?

Comment: You're missing a `}` in the last `\textsuperscript`.

Comment: Generally speaking, when compilation never stops, it usually means that the compiler is not able to reach the end of the document. In my experience, this also means a missing bracket or a missing `;` in a tikz component.

Answer (score 8):

As [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t) has already pointed out in a comment, the immediate problem is a missing `}` character after `2` in the expression `[N/m\textsuperscript{2]` in the final row of the table.

More generally, you may want to make the table [a lot!] more readable, say, by changing from 4 to 6 columns, so that the units of the parameters can be displayed in separate columns. Do also take the time to learn how to use the machinery of the `siunitx` package to display scientific units, and numbers, in a more LaTeX-y way, using the package's `\si` and `\num` macros.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,caption}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,},
         per-mode              = symbol,
         exponent-product      = \cdot,
         retain-unity-mantissa = false }
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}  % left-alignment, automatic math mode
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Input parameters associated with the hydraulic model} \label{parametersfinal}
\begin{tabular}{@{} Lll | Lll @{}}
$Symbol$ & Units & Value & 
$Symbol$ & Units & Value \\
\hline
T_{\textrm{ref}} & \si{\kelvin}$^{\strut}$ & \num{273,16} & 
   \kappa_s & - & \num{0,5e-3}\\
E_{f,\textrm{ref}} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{50e6} & 
   r & - & \num{0,04} \\ 
E_{f,\textrm{inc}} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared\per\kelvin} & \num{10e6} & 
   \beta & \si{(\newton\per\meter\squared)\raiseto{-1}} & \num{0,08e-6} \\
\nu_f & - & 0,45 & 
   \alpha & - & 9 \\
G_0 & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{700e6} &  
   p_{0,\textrm{ref}} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{-395e6} \\    
\kappa_0 & - & 0,01 & 
   m & - & 1 \\  
p^{*}_c & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{-40e3} & 
   (p^{*}_{y0})_{\mathrm{in}} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{-500e3} \\ 
\lambda_0 & - & 0,05 & 
   Y_{\textrm{ref}} & \si{\meter} & 0\\
\gamma & - & 1 & 
   \Delta p^{*}_{y0} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & 0 \\
k_t & - & 0,09 & 
   (S_{c,\textrm{seg}})_{\textrm{in}} & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{20e6} \\
M & - & \num{1,11} & 
   K_w & \si{\newton\per\meter\squared} & \num{1e9} \\  
\hline
\end{tabular}       
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

---

Just for the sake of comparison, here's a screenshot of your original table. In addition to having a more "cramped" look due to the use of just 4 columns, note that there are several typographic inconsistencies (highlighted in yellow) in the right-hand column, relating to either too much whitespace after the decimal marker or the use of a text-dash symbol instead of a mathematical-minus symbol. These inconsistencies are avoided automatically if one uses the `\num` macro.

[image]

Comment: A separate comment: It might make sense, in terms of enhancing the readability of the tabular material, to replace all instances of `\si{\newton\per\meter\squared}` with `\si{\pascal}`.

Answer (score 3):

More or less on the same basis, but I propose to put   units in their own column. Don't use the `center` environment with `table`: it will add unwanted vertical spacing. Use the `\centering` command instead. With `siunitx` you can define your own abbreviations for units.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx, caption}
\DeclareSIUnit{\Nsqm}{\N\per\square\m}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
    \sisetup{per-mode =symbol, exponent-product=\cdot, copy-decimal-marker}
        \caption{Input parameters associated with the hydraulic model} \label{parametersfinal}
        \begin{tabular}{lll|lll}
            \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Parameter} & \textbf{Value} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries Parameter} & \textbf{Value}\\
            \hline
            $T_\text{ref}$ & [K] & \num{273,16}& $\kappa_s$ & -- & \num{0,5e-3}\\
            $E_{f,\text{ref}}$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{50 e6} & $r$ & -- & \num{0,04} \\
            $E_{f,\text{inc}}$ & [\si{{\Nsqm}\per\K}] & \num{10 e6} & $\beta$ & [\si{(\Nsqm)^{-1}}]& \num{0,08e-6}\\
            $\nu_f$ & -- & \num{0,45} & $\alpha$ & -- & 9 \\
            $G_0$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{700 e6} & $p_{0, \text{ref}}$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{-395e6} \\
            $\kappa_0$ & -- & 0,01 & \si{m} &– & 1 \\
            $p^{*}_c$ & [N/m\textsuperscript{2}] & \num{-40 e3} & $(p^{*}_{y0})_{\text{in}}$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{-500 e3} \\
            $\lambda_0$ & -- & \num{0,05} & $Y_\text{ref}$ & [m] & 0\\
            $\gamma$ & -- & 1 & $\Delta p^{*}_{y0}$ & \si{\Nsqm}] & 0 \\
            $k_t$ & -- & \num{0,09} & $(S_{c,\text{seg}})_\text{in}$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{20 e6} \\
            $M$ & -- & \num{1,11} & $K_w$ & [\si{\Nsqm}] & \num{e9} \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

a small variation of nice [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) answer. differences are:

- columns with units use `s` column specifier
- columns with numbers use `S` column specifier

due to this changes the table code is slightly shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{input-symbols = {( - )},
         output-decimal-marker = {,},
         exponent-product      = \cdot,
         table-unit-alignment  = left
         }
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}  % left-alignment, automatic math mode

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\caption{Input parameters associated with the hydraulic model}
\label{parametersfinal}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.1}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} LsS | LsS @{}}
$Symbol$            &   \mcc{Units}                         & {Value }
    & $Symbol$          &   \mcc{Units}                             & {Value}   \\
    \hline
T_{\textrm{ref}}    & \kelvin                               & 273,16
    & \kappa_s          & {-}                                       & 0,5e-3    \\
E_{f,\textrm{ref}}  & \pascal             & 50e6
    & r                 & {-}                                       & 0,04      \\
E_{f,\textrm{inc}}  & \pascal\per\kelvin  & 10e6
    & \beta             & \per\pascal                               &   80e-9   \\
\nu_f               & -                                     & 0,45
    &    \alpha         & -                                         & 9         \\
G_0 &  \pascal                            &  700e6
    & p_{0,\textrm{ref}}& \pascal                                   &  -395e6   \\
\kappa_0 & - & 0,01 &
   m & - & 1 \\
p^{*}_c             & \pascal             & -40e3
    & (p^{*}_{y0})_{\mathrm{in}}
                        & \pascal                                   & -500e3    \\
\lambda_0           & -                                     & 0,05
    & Y_{\textrm{ref}}  & \meter                                    & 0         \\
\gamma              & -                                     & 1
    & \Delta p^{*}_{y0} & \pascal                                   & 0         \\
k_t                 & -                                     & 0,09
    & (S_{c,\textrm{seg}})_{\textrm{in}}
                        &  \pascal                                  & 20e6      \\
M                   & -             &  1,11
    & K_w               &  \pascal                                  & 1e9       \\
    \hline

\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. Very nice enhancements for the `s` column. :-) While you're at it, you might also replace all instances of `\newton\per\meter\squared` with `\pascal`, to further reduce the (code) clutter. Not sure, though, whether the alignment of the numbers in columns 3 and 6 on the respective (implicit or explicit) decimal markers is an improvement relative to simple left-alignment.

Comment: @Mico, i see this, but din't figured out what is behind that op one ones use "pascal" and ones it definitions .... i will corrected to "pascal" asap.

Comment: @Mico, oh here is now quite late and it seems that i'm quite tired from work in my family garden :-). i will check this again and correct asap.